# Ember Model - Manually resetting changes does not always reset hasDirtyAttributes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember model called `client`. It has attributes `name`, `auditRate`, and `toDelete` which defaults to `false` (I cannot post the actual code because this is a company-internal project). The `toDelete` attribute is meant to be toggle-able via a checkbox. Naturally, when the box is checked and `toDelete` is marked as `true`, the `client`'s `hasDirtyAttributes` flag is also set to `true`. And also naturally (I would think), when the box is subsequently unchecked and `toDelete` is marked as `false` – assuming no other changes have been made – the `client`'s `hasDirtyAttributes` flag is also set to `false`. This is how it generally works.

However, occasionally, when the box is unchecked, `hasDirtyAttributes` remains set to `true`, even though no other changes have been made to the model (at least not manually or purposefully).

Without being able to inspect my code, would anybody be able to tell why that might be happening sometimes but not others?

Comment: Are you using an input helper?

Comment: try to provide a minimal example by extracting your relevant code into a new project.